# $N$ independent geometric Random Variables and their matchings

Tags: probability

> Suppose we have $n$ independent geometric RVs $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n$ all with same $p \in (0,1]$. We say a pair $(i,j)$, $1\leq i<j\leq n$ matches if $X_i = X_j.$ Let $N$ denote the number of matches.
>
> Then, if $E_{(i,j)}$ is the event $(i,j)$ matches, what is $P(E_{(i,j)})$ and $E(N)$. Also find $\operatorname{Var}(N)$ if $p=.5$?

- For finding $P(E_{(i,j)})$ I did

  $$P(E_{(i,j)}) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}P(X_i=k)P(X_j=k) = \frac{p}{2-p}.$$

  I believe this is right but correct me if I'm wrong.
- Then for finding $E(N)$:

  For each pair create an indicator variable $I_{(i,j)}$ that is $1$ if that pair matches, $0$ otherwise.

  Then $N=\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq n} I_{(i,j)}$ and since each indicator has expectation $p/(2-p)$, I got that

  $$ E(N) = \binom{n}{2} \frac{p}{2-p}.$$

  Again please let me know if this is wrong.
- What I'm having trouble with is calculating the variance.

  I'm not sure if each $E_{(i,j)}$ is independent. If they are independent then I think the variance is $\binom{n}{2} p(1-p)$. Not sure how to solve this if they are not, so I think they are independent but how would I prove that they are independent?

Comment: Which version of the geometric distribution are you using? $P(X=k) = p(1-p)^k$ for $k \ge 0$, or $P(X=k)= p(1-p)^{k-1}$ for $k \ge 1$?

Comment: The second one!

Answer (score 1):

Define a set $S\subseteq [n]^2$ by $S=\Big\{(i,j)\in[n]^2\Big|1\leq i<j\leq n\Big\}$. We can express $V(N)$ by $$V(N)=\sum_{(i,j)\in S}V\big(I_{(i,j)}\big)+\sum_{(i_1,j_1),(i_2,j_2)\in S\\(i_1,j_1)\neq (i_2,j_2)}\text{cov}\big(I_{(i_1,j_1)},I_{(i_2,j_2)}\big)$$

The trick here is to recognize that if $i_1,i_2,j_1,j_2$ are all distinct then $E_{(i_1,j_1)},E_{(i_2,j_2)}$ are independent. This means only $n(n-1)(n-2)$ remain with a non$-$vanishing covariance so we can express $V(N)$ as  $$V(N)={n \choose 2}\cdot V\big(I_{(1,2)}\big)+n(n-1)(n-2)\cdot \text{cov}\big(I_{(1,2)},I_{(1,3)}\big)$$ Now we have $$V\big(I_{(1,2)}\big)=\mathbb{E}\big(I_{(1,2)}^2\big)-\Big(\mathbb{E}\big(I_{(1,2)}\big)\Big)^2=\frac{2p(1-p)}{(p-2)^2}$$ $$\text{cov}\big(I_{(1,2)},I_{(1,3)}\big)=P(X_1=X_2=X_3)-\mathbb{E}\big(I_{(1,2)}\big)\mathbb{E}\big(I_{(1,3)}\big)=\frac{p^2}{p^2-3p+3}-\frac{p^2}{(p-2)^2}$$ We got $V(N)$.

Comment: Shouldn't the variance of the indicator variable be successP(1-successP) or $V(I_{(i,j)}) = (\frac{p}{2-p})(1-\frac{p}{2-p})$

Comment: @LTM If you combine the fractions you have then you'll get what I have

Comment: I think the denominator should be squared?

Comment: Yes! Thank you.

Comment: Could you explain a bit on how you counted the number of non-vanishing covars?

Comment: Count the number of terms *in the sum*  taking the forms $$\text{cov}\big(I_{(i,j)},I_{(i,k)}\big),\text{cov}\big(I_{(j,i)},I_{(k,i)}\big),\text{cov}\big(I_{(i,j)},I_{(k,i)}\big),\text{cov}\big(I_{(j,i)},I_{(i,k)}\big)$$ then add them all up. Notice the number of terms in the sum looking like $\text{cov}\big(I_{(j,i)},I_{(k,i)}\big)$ equals the number of terms looking like $\text{cov}\big(I_{(i,j)},I_{(i,k)}\big)$, and same goes for the last two.

Comment: For example, if you want to count the number of terms in the sum that look like $\text{cov}\big(I_{(i,j)},I_{(i,k)}\big)$ you should first notice that for any fixed $i\in \{1,\ldots, n-2\}$ there are $(n-i)(n-i-1)$ possible choices for distinct $j,k>i$ so the number of terms that look like $\text{cov}\big(I_{(i,j)},I_{(i,k)}\big)$ equals $$\sum_{i=1}^{n-2}(n-i)(n-i-1)=\frac{1}{3}n(n-1)(n-2)$$